# How to embed a wearable apk into a mobile apk using ant rather than gradle

Tags: android, ant, gradle, wear-os

Our company has a huge complex ant build system for building an enormous suite of dozens and dozens of android projects that all get built into a single .apk.

I would like to incorporate a wearable app into this but I don't know to get the wearable .apk embedded within the mobile .apk.

In Android Studio / Gradle this embedded is automatically handled by simply adding the wear apk as a dependency of the mobile apk within the mobile's build.gradle.

Does anybody know how to get the wear apk embedded within the mobile apk when gradle is not being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Packaging Wearable Apps training has all of the steps for [packaging manually](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#PackageManually):

> 1. Include all the permissions declared in the manifest file of the wearable app in the manifest file of the mobile app. For example, if you specify the `VIBRATE` permission for the wearable app, you must also add that permission to the mobile app.
> 2. Ensure that both the wearable and mobile APKs have the same package name and version number.
> 3. Copy the signed wearable app to your handheld project's res/raw directory. We'll refer to the APK as `wearable_app.apk`.
> 4. Create a `res/xml/wearable_app_desc.xml` file that contains the version and path information of the wearable app. For example:

```
<wearableApp package="wearable.app.package.name">
   <versionCode>1</versionCode>
   <versionName>1.0</versionName>
   <rawPathResId>wearable_app</rawPathResId> 
</wearableApp>
```

> 5. Add a meta-data tag to your handheld app's `<application>` tag to reference the `wearable_app_desc.xml` file.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.wearable.beta.app"
  android:resource="@xml/wearable_app_desc"/>
```

> 6. Build and sign the handheld app.

Many of these steps can be done just a single time - the most important step is #3, in which you copy the resulting Wearable APK into the correct place before building your app.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you do step 6 without gradle? The instructions here are for using gradle from the command line: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

Comment: Step 6 is what your ant script does already to build your app - from the script's perspective, your app just has an extra raw resource, XML file, and manifest entry.

Comment: I followed the instructions but at installation time of the mobile apk I can see an error from WearablePkgInstaller saying "Failed to load checksum for wearable package". Do you have any thoughts what the problem could be? The wear and mobile apks are signed using the same credentials, the wear's permissions are in the mobile's manifest, and they have the same package name.